# Loop through several objects in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to check for something though several comboboxes, and I thought about looping though them because their names are as follows:

- ComboBox1
- ComboBox2
- ComboBox3
- ComboBox4
- ...
- ComboBoxn

What I'd like to run is something like:

```
If pcbN.Length <> ComboBoxN.Items.Count Then
        ' Take care of this
    End If
```

N representing the index.

Is there any way to do this, or must I write the same code for each object?

Thanks

Comment: write one loop, put it in a function.  send each CBO to it.  If you want, you can store references to the CBOs in an array or list and loop on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming they are all on the same container (i.e your form or the same panel) You can use `Container.Controls.OfType(ComboBox)` to get only the Comboboxes. you can loop over this controls with a simple for or foreach loop.

```
For Each item As ComboBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)
    ' Do your thing...
Next
```

For more information about the `OfType` method, read [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) in MSDN.